# Generate font from an image of text

Tags: image-processing, fonts, ocr

> Is it possible to generate a specific
>   set of font from the below given image
>   ?
>
> My idea is to generate a specific font
>   for the below given image of text ,by
>   manually selecting portion of the
>   image and mapping it to a set of
>   letter's.Generate the font for this
>   and then use this font to make it
>   readable for an OCR.Is generation of
>   font possible using any open-source
>   implementation ? Also please suggest
>   any good OCR's.

[image]

Comment: I would think those descenders on the y and g would confuse most OCR programs.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx:Have you used any good OCR ?

Comment: tesseract was the best I've ever used, and it's pretty good on standard fixed-font and some proportional fonts.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx:My idea is to manually select potions of the text and map it to a letter font so that the ocr can read easily.Is that possible according to your opinion ?

Comment: sure it's *possible*; but IMO it'll be a hell of a lot of work!

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx:How to generate font ?

Comment: I've never done it. Google "training tesseract" for some ideas.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to unless you have a MUCH higher resolution image.

Comment: I mean, for decent results it would be impossible, but it's hard to tell what you're aiming at from this question. For something as bad as this, maybe it would be less work just finding a similar font with a service like WhatTheFont (google it).

Comment: @Camilo Martin: The aim is to make the above image readable by an ocr. WhatTheFont say's it's too complex to be processed.

Comment: WhatTheFont *Is* an OCR. I really would first try getting a similar font, look here: http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=603

Answer (score 1):

Abbyy FineReader 10 gets better than expected results but predictably gets confused when the characters touch.

Your problem is that the line spacing is too small.  The descenders of each line overlap the character bounding boxes of the characters in the line directly below.  This makes character segmentation almost impossible because the characters are touching and overlapping. The number of combinations of overlapping characters is virtually impossible to train for.  The 'g' and 'y' characters are the worst offenders.

A double line spaced version of this would probably OCR reasonably well.

A custom solution that segmented and separated the each line along with a good dictionary would definitely improve the results. There would still be some errors to correct manually though.  The custom routine would have to deal with the ascenders and descenders and try and segment the image into lines which can then be fed to a decent OCR engine.  One way would be to analyse every character blob on the page and allocate it to a line.  Leptonica (www.leptonica.com - C Imaging Library) would probably make this job a little easier.

I would not try this without increasing the resolution to 200 or 300 dpi first.

With this custom solution, training a font becomes an option if the OCR engine does a poor job initially.

Abbyy (www.abbyy.com) or Google Tesseract OCR 3.00 would be a good place to start.

No guarantees as to whether all of this will work though.  This is quite a difficult page to OCR and you need to work out whether it is better to have it typed up manually overseas.  It depends on the number of pages to need to process.